# Magento automatically export file after checkout success

Tags: magento, csv, export

I recently installed a Magento module to export orders in CSV, but i would need to make Magento export the file i need directly after checkout.

I saw the module uses this kind of code to make the export happen:

```
$file = Mage::getModel('bluejalappeno_orderexport/export_csv')->exportOrders($orders);
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($file, file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('export').'/'.$file));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

I tried pasting the same code into Success.phtml, but i get an error saying "Invalid method", i made a research and found out that the class which invokes the method has to extend the class "Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action", but i don't know how to implement this in a phtml file..

Does someone know how or even better, know a different method to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: I only had time to try this method today, it gives me this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Bluejalappeno_Orderexport_Model_Observer::_prepareDownloadResponse() in /home/freemaeu/public_html/app/code/community/Bluejalappeno/Orderexport/Model/Observer.php on line 30

Answer (score 0):

As for a different method you should use an observer to attach to the a order success event, `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` seems like a good one if you are using onepage checkout. See more @ http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

To use an observer you need to create a custom module.

Add to your config.xml

```
<global>
    ...
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <namespace_modulename_observer>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>exportCsvOnCheckout</method>
                </namespace_modulename_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
    ...
</global>
```

Create `Model/Observer.php` in your custom module.

```
<?php
class Invent_Healthystart_Model_Observer
{
    public function exportCsvOnCheckout($observer)
    {
        ..put your logic here..
        Mage::log($observer); // $observer has varying amounts of access to models depending on the event
    }
}
```

Now when you do a successful order it will fire the observer which will fire your method and if you get your logic right it will fire the CSV export.

Note `_prepareDownloadResponse` is a admin specific method I think, so you wont be able to use it on the front end.

If the order process times out first thing to check is on how you are using the `$observer` as it can be very large.

As for the actual logic, it is going to be hard to advise you as you have provided us three lines of code, but it should be fairly trivial.

Comment: Thanks for help!

I implemented this and i get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Bluejalappeno_Orderexport_Model_Observer::_prepareDownloadResponse() in /home/freemaeu/public_html/app/code/community/Bluejalappeno/Orderexport/Model/Observer.php on line 30

it's surely related to the method being only available to admins, is there *any* way to use it in the frontend?

Comment: @TheHacker66 Basically it is saying that the method does not exist Ii don't think `_prepareDownloadResponse()` will be accessible on `$this` everywhere, you are going to probably need a `Mage::something`->__prepareDownloadResponse()` to get access to it.

Comment: Tried that too now. Seems i can't call a protected function from outside..

Fatal error: Call to protected method Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_prepareDownloadResponse() from context 'Bluejalappeno_Orderexport_Model_Observer' in /home/freemaeu/public_html/app/code/community/Bluejalappeno/Orderexport/Model/Observer.php on line 30

Comment: Yeah the only time I have used that method is in grids, there is probably another way to generate a download request.